# Start scrapy from Flask route

Tags: python, flask, scrapy

I want to build a crawler which takes the URL of a webpage to be scraped and returns the result back to a webpage. Right now I start scrapy from the terminal and store the response in a file. How can I start the crawler when some input is posted on to Flask, process, and return a response back?

Comment: Sorry, that last line is a little fuzzy. What are you doing with Flask? What process? And return the response back to where?

Comment: I'm using FLASK to expose the endpoints, so that from a web-app someone can post an input i.e. the webpage link to be scraped. Then, I want to start the spider and pass that input and return the crawler response back to web-app.

Comment: I just answered similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36384286/how-to-integrate-flask-scrapy

Answer (score 3):

You need to create a CrawlerProcess inside your Flask application and run the crawl programmatically. See the [docs](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html#run-scrapy-from-a-script).

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    # Your spider definition
    ...

process = CrawlerProcess({
    'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)'
})

process.crawl(MySpider)
process.start() # The script will block here until the crawl is finished
```

Before moving on with your project I advise you to look into a Python task queue (like [rq](http://python-rq.org/)). This will allow you to run Scrapy crawls in the background and your Flask application will not freeze while the scrapes are running.

Comment: I have used it under scrapy. Will you please provide some code snippet, which is running spider under flask application????